# How to add private directory of modules to system path in Python

Tags: python, system

I need to know how to add my library, that contains modules (functions and classes) that are going to be used in other modules, to Python path, so to use the library like scikit-learn, etc. I tried what was in the answer to a previous similar question, but doesn't work.
My system is Windows 10 and I work with Python 3.10.9 in Visual Studio 1.18.

I have tried:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('E:\\machine_learning\\my_lib')
```

but this code:

```py
import sys      
def check_library_import(library_name):     
    if library_name in sys.modules:     
        print(f"La libreria '{library_name}' è stata correttamente importata.")     
    else:       
        print(f"La libreria '{library_name}' non è stata importata.")       
        # Sostituisci 'lib_madre' con il nome effettivo del tuo pacchetto madre
library_name = 'E:\machine_learning\my_lib'     
check_library_import(library_name)
```

says that the library hasn't been imported

Comment: what is the contents of the E:\machine_learning\my_lib ?

Comment: 1) use raw strings or quote the \ characters.. 2) you are not importing anything, you are just trying to add something that does not even work to sys.path ..

Comment: That  is not the way `sys.path` works. It only declare *folders* where the import machinery should search Python modules or packages. Then `sys.modules` contains the *name* (not path) of the modules that has been successfully imported (via `import` or `importlib`).

Comment: I listed the wrong code; the code I used for checking the importing  of my library is:

import sys  
def check_library_import(library_name):  
    if library_name in sys.modules:  
        print(f"La libreria '{library_name}' è stata correttamente importata.")  
    else:  
        print(f"La libreria '{library_name}' non è stata importata.")
library_name = 'E:\machine_learning\my_lib'  
check_library_import(library_name)  
Sorry for the mistake

Comment: Is there a specific reason for adding the path? If you want to use a local python package as a library you can just install it with `pip install -e E:\machine_learning\my_lib` and then use it in your code by importing it like any other library